# how to create a dictionary using lists in a python class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to create a portfolio class. I want to zip my two lists into a dictionary but when a i try to print it out, it is empty(even though my lists are not). Am i missing something??

```
import numpy as np

class Portfolio(object):
    """description of class"""

    array_of_stock_prices=[]
    array_of_stock_names=[]
    #create a dictionary of stocks
    stocks=dict(zip(array_of_stock_names,array_of_stock_prices))


    def __init__(self):
        print()    

    def AddStock(self,stock_ticker,stock_price):
        self.array_of_stock_names.append(stock_ticker)
        self.array_of_stock_prices.append(stock_price)


    def printObject(self):
        for key,value in self.stocks.items():
            print(key,value)


port1=Portfolio()
port1.AddStock('AApl',100)
port1.printObject()
```

Comment: When you create the dictionary, the lists are empty

Comment: You initialize `stocks` only once.

Comment: your stocks dictionary is created before your call to `Addstock` i.e. the dict is created before your lists have any values. None of your functions modifies the dictionary, so it remains empty.

Comment: __WARNING__ your `array_of_stock_prices`,  ` array_of_stock_names` and `stocks` are class attributes (shared between all instances of the class). I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Also, why do you want to maintain two lists _and_ a dict instead of a single dict ? This violates the SPOT rule (=>"Single Point Of Truth").

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so what do you propose? Is it better to create them with the constructor(_init_)? How can I get access to them? Thank you

Comment: It's not a question of "is it better", it's a question of what you want. If you want instance attributes then yes, you have to create them in the initializer (`__init__`). You just create them as `self.whatever = something`... And really, don't use two lists when what you want is a dict - just create a dict (or an OrderedDict if insertion order matters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the dictionary only once, with empty lists. If you want to keep it up to date, put that line of code after every extension of the lists (in the end of `AddStock`), and keep this dictionary as an attribute of `self`, like

```
self.stocks = dict(zip(self.array_of_stock_names, self.array_of_stock_prices))
```